# Code okay and yet I get error - XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: android, xml

I am taking the first step into android programming and XML. I am using the Big Nerd Ranch Guide book. In Eclipse, I used the XML given in the book and I got the error XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

How do I fix this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="@string/question_text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >    
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error? I put it in Eclipse and didn't get that error.

Comment: @hichris123 - Thanks. Its probably some problem with eclipse. I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. I removed the code and saved the xml file. After that, I replaced it with the above code and saved. The error is gone. It was probably a remanant from the time when "automatically build project" was enabled.

Strange.